# Java Web Application multiple user session handling

Tags: java, session, jsf, glassfish

I use Glassfish server 3.1.1, and I successfully configured my realm for the usergroups.

While only 1 user is logged in, everything works fine, but as I log in with another account from a different browser (or even a different computer), the first session is cleared and the last logged in users data is shown in every previous sessions.

I'm using Netbeans, and I let it generate my entity classes from a postgreSQL database, then the JSF pages from the entities. 
I read about HttpSessions, but there wasn't everything clear to me. Shall I continue this way, or the solution is in a different direction? If this is the right way, could anyone send me a sample source?

Here is my code:

Login.xhtml:

```
<h:inputText id="email" size="25" value="#{login.email}" maxlength="30"/>
<h:inputSecret id="password" size="25" value="#{login.password}" maxlength="100"/>
<h:commandLink value="Bejelentkezés" action="#{login.loginAction}"/>
```

This is how my login class looks like:

```
@ManagedBean(name="login")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean
{

private String email;
private String password;

public String loginAction()
{
    HttpServletRequest req=(HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getRequest();
    try
    {
        System.out.println("login with: " + email + ", " + password + ".");
        req.login(email, password);
    }
    catch(ServletException e) ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code posted so far looks fine.

> *but as I log in with another account from a different browser (or even a different computer), the first session is cleared and the last logged in users data is shown in every previous sessions.*

This problem is caused elsewhere than in the code posted so far. The session should not be cleared at all. This is likely a misinterpretation of the happening. Perhaps you don't understand the concept "session". The symptoms indicate that you're apparently getting hold of the logged-in user in some `static` variable or an `@ApplicationScoped` managed bean. Make sure that you aren't doing that.

As to how the "session" works, please read this: [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909).

As to how to choose the proper managed bean scope, please read this: [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)